# Can I install Ubuntu 14.04 on a 8 GB ssd harddrive?

Tags: ssh, ssd, sata

I d like to buy a [Lenovo Ideapad z510](https://www.cyberport.de/?DEEP=1C31-2G9) Laptop which has got a 508GB SSH harddrive (it s 500 GB SATA and 8 GB SSD). The preinstalled OS is DOS, I want to replace it with ubuntu

1. Is the 8 GB SSD harddrive large enough to install Ubuntu 14.04 on it?
2. What is going to happen if the SSD harddrive is too small? Will Ubuntu still be installed properly?

Comment: You likely have a hybrid drive (SSHD) where then SSD typically is not exposed. Access to the SSD is done by the drive's firmware. They should just work like any hard drive: see e.g. http://askubuntu.com/questions/380778/do-ssd-hd-hybrids-increase-performance-in-ubuntu and http://askubuntu.com/questions/143033/will-a-laptop-with-hybrid-hdd-ssd-run-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. 5GB is [considered](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements) the minimum. I think you could probably get away with even less.
2. It wouldn't allow you to start the installation if you didn't have enough space.